# how to read data from array using sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, sqliteopenhelper

I want to making an app where i want to extract the data from array using the sqlite database and the example of array is given below, there are two strings and one image....there are many items in array which i want to display in a list form by using the recycler view.

Help me how should i do that.

Here is my code :

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationDetailsHolder> {

    private List<NotificationHolder> notificationHolderList;

    public NotificationAdapter() {
        notificationHolderList = new ArrayList<>();

        notificationHolderList.add(new NotificationHolder("Name", "Details",R.drawable.image)
        ));  

    }

    @Override
    public NotificationDetailsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_layout_workshop,parent,false);
        return new NotificationDetailsHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationDetailsHolder holder, int position) {

        NotificationHolder notificationHolder = notificationHolderList.get(position);
        holder.bindData(notificationHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationHolderList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to set the data to your pojo class.

**Activity Code :**

```
 private void setData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        ArrayList<LoadDataResult> cList = new ArrayList<LoadDataResult>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;

        db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                LoadDataResult product = new LoadDataResult();
                product.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                product.setSku(cursor.getString(2));
                product.setUpc(cursor.getString(3));
                product.setAssoc_upc(cursor.getString(4));
                product.setPrice(cursor.getString(5));
                product.setDisplaySize(cursor.getString(6));
                product.setDisplaySizeYes(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(7))));
                product.setStatus(cursor.getString(8));
                Log.e("DATASQL",""+cursor.getString(3));

                // Adding contact to list
                Constants.cList.add(product);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          //  utils.hideDialog();
        }

}
```

After Setting data to pojo class send that `ArrayList` to `RecyclerAdapter` class by `setAdapter`.

```
adapter = new TakeInventoryAdapter(TakeInventoryResult.this, cList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```